# Extracting nouns from a long list of words

Tags: php, regex

I have a long list of words(only alphabets) and I need only nouns in them. Whats the best way to do this in PHP?

Comment: How can you identify a noun from a non-noun using regular expressions?

Answer (score 4):

Download the wordnet library (http://wordnet.princeton.edu/), and compare your list against theirs.

Comment: that is really neat, didn't know about that library

Answer (score 0):

This might be a very late answer but would be helpful to others with the same question.Use POS tagger,very easy to use.

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml